# Evaluate continued fraction

Tags: functions, number-theory

*Mathematica* has the `ContinuedFraction[]` function to give the continued fraction expansion of a rational (or approximation of a real) number.  I'm interested in the inverse: is there an efficient way to give an array as a continued fraction expansion and have *Mathematica* calculate the number it represents?

Comment: There's [`FromContinuedFraction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromContinuedFraction.html)

Comment: Every Mathematica function ref page has a "See also" section and a "More about" section. Looking there on the `ContinuedFraction` ref page would have given you links to `FromContinuedFraction` and the overview page "Continued Fractions & Rational Approximations". [The tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntegerAndNumberTheoreticalFunctions.html), also mentioned on the same page, contains a discussion of `FromContinuedFraction` as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Heike mentions in the comments, `FromContinuedFraction[]` does what you want:

```
FromContinuedFraction[{2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 16}]
6784/2891
```

If `FromContinuedFraction[]` had not been built-in, however, something like this could be done:

```
(* backward recursion *)
Fold[#2 + 1/#1 &, Infinity, Reverse[{2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 16}]]
6784/2891
```

or even

```
(* forward recursion, matrix multiplication form *)
Divide @@ Last[Fold[{{0, 1}, {1, #2}}.#1 &, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 16}]]
```

or equivalently

```
Divide @@ First[Fold[{{#2, 1}, {1, 0}}.#1 &, IdentityMatrix[2], {2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 16}]]
```

Still another alternative is

```
(* Lentz-Thompson-Barnett recursion *)
1/(Times @@ Flatten[Rest[FoldList[{#2 + 1/#1[[1]], 1/(#2 + #1[[2]])} &, {1, 0},
                                  {2, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 2, 16}]]] - 1)
```