# Building a continued fraction

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I've completed a problem that involves approximating $e$ by a continued fraction:

$$\frac{N_1}{D_1+\frac{N_2}{D_2+\frac{N_3}{\ddots+\frac{N_k}{D_k}}}}$$

with the $N_i$ being the list `{1,1,1, …}` and the $D_i$ being the list `{1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8, …}`.  (Note: The continued fraction actually approximates $e-2$).

The overarching structure of computing the continued fraction is a straightforward application of `Fold` with the following function defined:

```
f[x_, {m_, d_}] := m/(d+x);
eContFracApprox[n_] := Fold[f, 0, (*properly constructed list of pairs*)]
```

which shifts the crux of the problem to generating the lists for $N_i$ and $D_i$ and combining them properly.

I have a solution, but I'm not happy with it:

```
Reverse[
MapThread[
  List, {Table[1, {n}], 
   Take[Flatten[{Join[{1, 2}, Table[{1, 1, i}, {i, 4, n, 2}]]}],n]}
]
]
```

I think it's ugly and it doesn't work for values of $n < 3$.  Perhaps someone can suggest a different/better approach?  Specifically, I'd like to know if we can do away completely with `MapThread` and generate the list of pairs directly from an application of `Table`.

---

**Edit 1**:

Just to be clear.  I'm looking for an improvement to generating the lists of the $N_i$ and $D_i$.  Although, alternate ways of generating continued fractions are also appreciated.

I'll also add my complete function for reference:

```
eContinuedFractionApprox[n_Integer] := Module[{f},
  f[x_, {m_, d_}] := m/(d + x);
N[Fold[f, 0,
 Reverse[
  MapThread[List,
   {Table[1, {n}], Take[Flatten[{Join[{1, 2}, Table[{1, 1, i},
         {i, 4, n, 2}]]}],
     n]
    }
   ]
  ]
 ],
n
] + 2
 ]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you say, this is a straightforward application of `Fold`, which is also perhaps the cleanest solution you can get. I'm guessing that you're seeking `Table` based approaches since you didn't want to deal with having to "fold properly". I'll complete the `Fold` application here so that you can see how it is applied:

```
n = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5};
d = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5};

f[x_, {m_, d_}] := m/(d + x);
Fold[f, Last@n/Last@d, Reverse@Most@Transpose@{n, d}]
```

[image]

---

Now coming to generating a continued fraction approximation for $e-2$, observe that if you prepend a $1$ to the $D_i$ list you showed, then we can get a nice sequence function for it (I have replaced the formal symbols in the output with normal ones for clarity):

```
func = FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8}]
(* DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {-2 - y[n] - y[1 + n] - y[2 + n] + y[3 + n] + 
        y[4 + n] + y[5 + n] == 0, y[1] == 1, y[2] == 1, y[3] == 2, y[4] == 1, y[5] == 1}]] *)
```

So if you want to use $N$ terms in your approximation, just use the above function to obtain $N+1$ entries and discard the first one.

The `Fold` operation now can be written easily as (for 20 terms):

```
eMinus2Approx[n_Integer] := With[{d = N@Rest@func@Range[n + 1], f = 1/Plus[##] &},
    Fold[f, 1/Last@d, Reverse@Most@d]
]

eMinus2Approx[20]
(* 0.718282 *)
```

Comment: The fold procedure isn't the issue.  It's the list generation that I'm concerned with.  I'll edit my original post to reflect that.

Comment: @Haer'Dalis Please see my update for a way to generate the list.

Comment: That is a badass function (FindSequenceFunction).  I'm continually amazed at what's been built into MMA.  Thanks for that @rm-rf.

Answer (score 16):

Well, the smartass answer would be

```
ContinuedFraction[E - 2, n]
```

So your approximation function (if I understood correctly) would be

```
FromContinuedFraction[ContinuedFraction[E - 2, n]]
```

But the way I would generate this particular sequence manually is something along these lines:

```
ls[n_] := Module[{s}, s = 2 Range[n];
                 {1, Riffle[s, {{1, 1}}]} // Flatten]
```

Comment: was not aware of ContinuedFraction either.

Comment: yea usually it's a question of what Mathematica *doesn't* have. though i don't think i would have anticipated continued fraction functionality myself, and i don't remember how i happened upon it

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in the simple continued fraction representation for *any* irrational, not just $e-2$, then the following code generates the required list of coefficients, which are the $D_i$ in your notation. The number of coefficients requested is $n$ and the input irrational is $r$.

```
Map[-#[[1, 1]]&,Rest[NestList[1/(#-Floor[#])&,r,n]]]
```

For example, $r=\pi$ and $n=10$ returns
    {3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1}.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in function [`ContinuedFractionK[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinuedFractionK.html) seems to have not yet been mentioned, so:

```
n = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5};
d = {d1, d2, d3, d4, d5};
ContinuedFractionK[n[[k]], d[[k]], {k, 5}]
   (d5*(d4*(d2*d3*n1 + n1*n3) + d2*n1*n4) + (d2*d3*n1 + n1*n3)*n5)/
 (d5*(d4*(d3*(d1*d2 + n2) + d1*n3) + (d1*d2 + n2)*n4) + (d3*(d1*d2 + n2) + d1*n3)*n5)
```

A `Part::pspec` error is thrown in this case even when `ContinuedFractionK[]` possesses the `HoldAll` attribute; I am not quite sure why. Nevertheless, it works, and you can use `Quiet[]` if you find the messages somewhat annoying.

---

As already mentioned, `Fold[]` is indeed the function you can use for evaluating continued fractions had the CF-related functions not been built-in. rm has detailed the conventional "backward evaluation" method; I will present the forward recursion scheme (formulae 16-19 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html), which I also used in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7369)):

```
Divide @@ Last[Fold[{{0, 1}, #2}.#1 &, IdentityMatrix[2], Transpose[{n, d}]]]
```

Usually, this method is not used in inexact arithmetic since the recursions tend to produce results that overflow, even when their ratio is perfectly representable. In *Mathematica*, which allows for symbolics and exact arithmetic, one has no such fear. The methods I featured in my other answer can also be adapted accordingly (e.g. Lentz-Thompson-Barnett) to this more general form of the continued fraction.

---

For the specific case of $e-2$:

```
Divide @@ Last[Fold[{{0, 1}, #2}.#1 &, IdentityMatrix[2], 
    Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, 18],
               {1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 12, 1}}]]] // N
   0.718281828459028
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach to manually construct the list given by `ContinuedFraction[E-2, n]`:

```
cfList[n_] := {0} ~Join~ (Flatten @ Riffle[Table[{1, 1}, {n}], 2 Range @ n] ~Take~ {2, n})
```

Checking the result:

```
FromContinuedFraction[cfList @ 10] // N
E - 2.
(*
0.718284
0.718282
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

An extension to create a Ternary (or Bifurcating) Continued Fraction is:

```
F[{a_,b_},{c_,d_}]={c+b/a,d+1/a}
Fold[F,Reverse[{{a0,b0},{a1,b1},{a2,b2}}]]
```

See, for example, [Murru etal.](http://arxiv.org.ezproxy.utas.edu.au/pdf/1304.2906v1.pdf)