# Approximating Pi, fraction in another

Tags: approximation

In a previous exam, this question was asked:
We want to approximate Pi using this formula
 [image: formula]

Write a function that calculates the right hand side of this equation truncated at the nth term.
For example `f[3]` stops at `2 + 5^2/2`

I can't solve this, because I don't know how to write one fraction in another like this in *Mathematica*? What is the easy way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21998/18476