# Representing a general continued fraction in a list for ContinuedFraction

Tags: continued-fractions

The initial mathematical problem is to solve for $x$ in:

$$x = \sqrt{19} + \frac{91}{\sqrt{19} + \frac{91}{\sqrt{19} + \frac{91}{\sqrt{19} + \frac{91}{\sqrt{19} + \frac{91}{x}}}}}$$

(Notice the $x$ in the right-hand-side.)

The following direct substitution indeed gives the correct answer:

```
Solve[x == Sqrt[19]+ 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/x)))),x]
```

$\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{19}-\sqrt{383}\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{2}
   \left(\sqrt{19}+\sqrt{383}\right)\right\}\right\}$

I'm interested in solving the problem using `FromContinuedFraction`.  If I convert the problem *by hand* into the form for `ContinuedFraction`, I get:

`Solve[x == FromContinuedFraction[{Sqrt[19],Sqrt[19]/91, Sqrt[19],Sqrt[19]/91, Sqrt[19],x/91}],x]`

which yields the correct answer.

However, I'd like to *automatically* convert the right-hand-side of the initial equation into the form of `ContinuedFraction`--for this and related problems.

The obvious approach doesn't work:

```
ContinuedFraction[Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/(Sqrt[19] + 91/x))))]
```

How can I automatically extract the terms in the right-hand-side and place them in a list appropriate for `ContinuedFraction` and `FromContinuedFraction`?  Note that we cannot solve for $x$ and then express $x$ as a continued fraction because $x$ is a term *within* the continued fraction.

Comment: `Solve[x == Nest[91/# + Sqrt[19] &, x, 5]]`?

Comment: I like your solution ($+1$)... but it isn't for my problem.  How do I extract the desired list of coefficients needed for `ContinuedFraction`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the  purpose of converting the right side of the equation to `FromContinuedFraction[...]`? It can be done by using some code automatically, but why?

Comment: @Somos:  I want to solve the original equation by the method `Solve[x = ContinuedFraction[...],x]` as an alternate method, partly to show students the power of `ContinuedFraction[]`.  Indeed, one can use it in the "hand crafted" case I showed.  But for large, complex continued fractions, converting the CF "by hand" is arduous and error prone.  Hence I'd like to be able to perform this (i.e., get the list of coefficients) automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Not easy since getting the depth is awkward. You can write the equation as:

```
x == 91/ContinuedFractionK[91, If[n == 6, x, Sqrt[19]], {n, 6}]
```

You can put in dummy constants $a,b$ and use an `If` to switch to `x` at depth 6:

```
a/ContinuedFractionK[a, If[n == 6, x, b], {n, 6}]
```

You could use this form to `SolveAlways` which finds the coefficients that make it match the rhs of your equation - though I have to do `Last` as `SolveAlways` returns zero solutions:

```
sol = Last@
  SolveAlways[
   a/ContinuedFractionK[a, If[n == 6, x, b], {n, 6}] == expr[[2]], x]
```

Then you can solve by putting together the above:

```
Values@Flatten@
  Solve[x == (a/ContinuedFractionK[a, If[n == 6, x, b], {n, 6}]) /. 
    sol, x]
```

Unfortunately, none of that seems to be as convenient and general as you'd like. Also simply using `ContinuedFraction` instead of `ContinuedFractionK` is not going to work because `ContinuedFraction` has 1 as the numerators, not some custom number.

Comment: Thanks for the effort ($+1$), but it doesn't quite solve the general problem.  Let's see if someone else figures it out.

Answer (score 1):

[From this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21999/328):

There is the code:

```
n = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5};
d = {d2, d3, d4, d5, x};
f[y_, {m_, d_}] := m/(d + y);
d1 + Fold[f, Last@n/Last@d, Reverse@Most@Transpose@{n, d}]
```

which gives the output:

$$\text{d1}+\frac{\text{n1}}{\text{d2}+\frac{\text{n2}}{\text{d3}+\frac{\text{n3}}{\text{d4}+\frac{\text{n4}}{\text{d5}+\frac{\text{n5}}{x}}}}}$$

The code above can be modified into:

```
Clear[x, y, nn, n, j, d, d0, nnn];
nnn = 5;
Table[numerators = 
  Table[ToExpression[StringJoin["n", ToString[j]]], {j, 1, nn}];
 denominators = 
  Flatten[{Table[
     ToExpression[StringJoin["d", ToString[j]]], {j, 2, nn}], x}];
 f[y_, {m_, denominators_}] := m/(denominators + y);
 Solve[x == 
   d1 + Fold[f, Last@numerators/Last@denominators, 
     Reverse@Most@Transpose@{numerators, denominators}], x], {nn, 1, 
  nnn}]
```

which gives the output:

```
{{{x -> 1/2 (d1 - Sqrt[d1^2 + 4 n1])}, {x -> 
    1/2 (d1 + Sqrt[d1^2 + 4 n1])}}, {{x -> (
    d1 d2 + n1 - n2 - Sqrt[4 d1 d2 n2 + (-d1 d2 - n1 + n2)^2])/(
    2 d2)}, {x -> (
    d1 d2 + n1 - n2 + Sqrt[4 d1 d2 n2 + (-d1 d2 - n1 + n2)^2])/(
    2 d2)}}, {{x -> (1/(
    2 (d2 d3 + n2)))(d1 d2 d3 + d3 n1 + d1 n2 - d2 n3 - 
      Sqrt[(-d1 d2 d3 - d3 n1 - d1 n2 + d2 n3)^2 - 
       4 (d2 d3 + n2) (-d1 d2 n3 - n1 n3)])}, {x -> (1/(
    2 (d2 d3 + n2)))(d1 d2 d3 + d3 n1 + d1 n2 - d2 n3 + 
      Sqrt[(-d1 d2 d3 - d3 n1 - d1 n2 + d2 n3)^2 - 
       4 (d2 d3 + n2) (-d1 d2 n3 - n1 n3)])}}, {{x -> (d1 d2 d3 d4 + 
       d3 d4 n1 + d1 d4 n2 + d1 d2 n3 + n1 n3 - d2 d3 n4 - 
       n2 n4 - \[Sqrt]((-d1 d2 d3 d4 - d3 d4 n1 - d1 d4 n2 - 
            d1 d2 n3 - n1 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + n2 n4)^2 - 
          4 (d2 d3 d4 + d4 n2 + d2 n3) (-d1 d2 d3 n4 - d3 n1 n4 - 
             d1 n2 n4)))/(2 (d2 d3 d4 + d4 n2 + 
         d2 n3))}, {x -> (d1 d2 d3 d4 + d3 d4 n1 + d1 d4 n2 + 
       d1 d2 n3 + n1 n3 - d2 d3 n4 - 
       n2 n4 + \[Sqrt]((-d1 d2 d3 d4 - d3 d4 n1 - d1 d4 n2 - 
            d1 d2 n3 - n1 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + n2 n4)^2 - 
          4 (d2 d3 d4 + d4 n2 + d2 n3) (-d1 d2 d3 n4 - d3 n1 n4 - 
             d1 n2 n4)))/(2 (d2 d3 d4 + d4 n2 + 
         d2 n3))}}, {{x -> (d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 + d3 d4 d5 n1 + 
       d1 d4 d5 n2 + d1 d2 d5 n3 + d5 n1 n3 + d1 d2 d3 n4 + d3 n1 n4 +
        d1 n2 n4 - d2 d3 d4 n5 - d4 n2 n5 - 
       d2 n3 n5 - \[Sqrt]((-d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 - d3 d4 d5 n1 - 
            d1 d4 d5 n2 - d1 d2 d5 n3 - d5 n1 n3 - d1 d2 d3 n4 - 
            d3 n1 n4 - d1 n2 n4 + d2 d3 d4 n5 + d4 n2 n5 + 
            d2 n3 n5)^2 - 
          4 (d2 d3 d4 d5 + d4 d5 n2 + d2 d5 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + 
             n2 n4) (-d1 d2 d3 d4 n5 - d3 d4 n1 n5 - d1 d4 n2 n5 - 
             d1 d2 n3 n5 - n1 n3 n5)))/(2 (d2 d3 d4 d5 + d4 d5 n2 + 
         d2 d5 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + n2 n4))}, {x -> (d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 + 
       d3 d4 d5 n1 + d1 d4 d5 n2 + d1 d2 d5 n3 + d5 n1 n3 + 
       d1 d2 d3 n4 + d3 n1 n4 + d1 n2 n4 - d2 d3 d4 n5 - d4 n2 n5 - 
       d2 n3 n5 + \[Sqrt]((-d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 - d3 d4 d5 n1 - 
            d1 d4 d5 n2 - d1 d2 d5 n3 - d5 n1 n3 - d1 d2 d3 n4 - 
            d3 n1 n4 - d1 n2 n4 + d2 d3 d4 n5 + d4 n2 n5 + 
            d2 n3 n5)^2 - 
          4 (d2 d3 d4 d5 + d4 d5 n2 + d2 d5 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + 
             n2 n4) (-d1 d2 d3 d4 n5 - d3 d4 n1 n5 - d1 d4 n2 n5 - 
             d1 d2 n3 n5 - n1 n3 n5)))/(2 (d2 d3 d4 d5 + d4 d5 n2 + 
         d2 d5 n3 + d2 d3 n4 + n2 n4))}}}
```

from which it should be possible to spot the general pattern if you vary the variable `nnn=5`.

Comment: Well... "from which it should be possible to spot the general pattern if you vary the variable."  I appreciate your effort ($+1$), but "spotting the general pattern" simply eludes me, and generalizing to arbitrary problems seems tricky indeed.  Regardless, after all this work we don't get the list of terms needed for ContinuedFraction (or ContinuedFractionK).

Comment: Try setting `nnn=9` or greater. To me there is a pattern, at least initially. The key seems to  be to sort the factors in the terms according to index regardless of letter `d` or `n`.